# Powershell copy, retain folder structure

Tags: powershell

Im trying to achieve the following, get computers name from a txt file, search for particulat file extension, copy the files along with folder structure and in destination create folder based on the computer name and paste there, please see my powershell commands below, when im trying with single computer it works fine, but when adding mutiple computers im getting error.

Please tell me what are the modifications required? Thanks in advance

```
$computername = Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\computers.txt"
$src = "\\$ComputerName\c$\test"
  Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse *.opt |  foreach {
  $split = $_.Fullname  -split '\\'
  $DestFile =  $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\' 
  $DestFile =  "C:\Test1\$DestFile"
  $null = New-Item -Path  $DestFile -Type File -Force
  Copy-Item -Path  $_.FullName -Destination $DestFile -Force
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `$computername` is an array of strings, you have to also iterate.

Comment: You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Don't try to re-invent it in PowerShell unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, iterate the lines read from computers.txt:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\28\SO_51572359.ps1

$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\computers.txt"

ForEach($ComputerName in $computers){
    $src = "\\$ComputerName\c$\test"
    Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse *.opt | ForEach-Object {
        $split = $_.Fullname  -split '\\'
        $DestFile =  $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\' 
        $DestFile =  "C:\Test1\$DestFile"
        $null = New-Item -Path  $DestFile -Type File -Force
        Copy-Item -Path  $_.FullName -Destination $DestFile -Force
    }
}
```

Sample tree after running script:

```
> tree c:\Test1 /F
Folder PATH listing for volume ThisPC
Volume serial number is 0000xxxx xxxx:xxxx
C:\TEST1
└───RemotePC
    └───c$
        └───test
                Test.opt
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, i can get the files from remote computers, however im getting below error, is it related to the permission?                                              Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\\c$\Program Files\' because it does not exist.
At line:3 char:5
+     Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse *.opt | ForEach-Object {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\\c$\Program Files\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Id the file/path does exist depite the message, it is quite likely a rights problem.